# Maya – Setting frame range programmatically with the Render Setup API

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to set the Start frame with the renderSetup Python api in Maya 2022 like this:

```
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup
import maya.cmds as cmds

rs = renderSetup.instance()  
rl = rs.createRenderLayer('NewLayer')
sf = rl.createAbsoluteOverride('defaultRenderGlobals', 'startFrame')
sf.setAttrValue(20)
```

[image]

For some reason the value '20' gets translated in '0.0800'. How to set it to the proper value?

Comment: I found that multiplying the value with '250' outputs correct values. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 0.004 frame issue

It's a [Great Old Issue](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/incorrect-value-when-setting-an-override-for-start-end-frame/td-p/6431550) of Maya's Render Setup editor. Use additional multiplier 250, because initial frame value for some reason is still `0.004` frame. Use the following math if you need a frame 20:

```
0.004 x 20 x 250 = 20
```

The only possible explanation for this nonsense is the implementation of a preset with a frame rate of `23.98 fps` instead of `23.976 fps`. This is where Maya engineers "lost" `0.004` frame. This is my thought and it may be wrong but as Final Cut Pro evangelist, I admit that thought...

So, according to your code you need to write this:

```
sf = rl.createAbsoluteOverride('defaultRenderGlobals', 'startFrame')
sf.setAttrValue(20*250)
```

Comment: Sounds like a logic explanation. Will go with the '250 multiply' then :)